# How can I import a BlogML file into my WordPress site?

Tags: import, bulk-import

I have an old blog using BlogEngine.NET 3.0.  The only export is has is to a BlogML file

Is there still a way to import that into my WordPress 5.1.1 blog?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have solution on it you can use old wordpress version which is near on 2014 release after that use this plugin and import it https://github.com/maniserowicz/blogml-wordpress-import

after that export files and import on latest version of wordpress thats it
i hope its will help you .